# Is the etcd clustering design suitable for reliable key/value replication applications?

Tags: etcd

I know this isn't a pure programming question, but I'm developing a distributed appliance management application that has a need for reliably sharing/replicating data across multiple servers/VMs, without the heavy orchestration of a typical database.

Is etcd clustering actually a reliable architecture for key/value replication in a cluster?

This is all supposed to be automated and since I'm starting with Atomic/Core OS, and etcd is already present, I stood up a 4 node cluster with full TLS and some user/role configuration to play with. I went as far as developing a library to read/write/export the data structures my application requires.

The etcd v3 documentation isn't as clear on some of the more revealing points that the v2 documentation was.

I was hoping for peer-to-peer replication of data, assuming connectivity between at least 1 other node in the cluster. If a node was unable to reach the rest of the cluster, its store would be available locally and I could codify how I want my appliance to deal with being "offline" for too long, until it re-establishes it availability.

I'm going to describe some of the limitations I've encountered with clustered etcd, and maybe someone can comment whether its the right solution for my job. This isn't a compliant session, I just want to understand if I'm using the wrong solution.

1. **Availability/fail-over is impossible when only 2 nodes are in a cluster:** I started with a 2 node configuration and setup a working cluster (eg put/get data from one to the other, replication works, etc...) When one goes down, the other enters endless leader election mode. It's the only one, yet raft needs at least 1 other node available to elect a leader. So fail-over needs at least 3 etcd nodes, so if 1 goes down, the other 2 can pick a leader. *I'm really floored by this limitation. I must be doing something wrong.*
2. **Joining a new etcd node to a cluster requires almost all details about the existing cluster:** When joining a new node, the member needs to be added in advance (with its peering connection details), then on the new node, you have to start etcd with cluster-state "existing" and initial-cluster to contain exactly all nodes in the cluster with their names and peer urls. This is a pretty synchronized procedure because after you join, everything is stored in the data directory. So subsequent starts don't need any cluster configuration at all. I find this makes adding a node kind of fragile, and kind of unnecessary as the cluster already knows about you (you had to add them as a member).
3. **During the leader election process you can't access any node's keys/values:** When a node goes down, no get/put requests are serviced. If you only have 2 nodes in the cluster, the election process never ends (see #1), so your application will never get access to that data, resulting in a bit of a cascading failure.

If anyone is interested in testing etcd out for this kind of stuff, I included my scripting below used (I left out the TSL configuration bits) in my testing. I don't expect anyone to test this for me.

```
# On the 1st node (I used Centos7 minimal, with etcd installed)
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2379/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2380/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

export CL_NAME=etcd1
export HOST=$(hostname)
export IP_ADDR=$(ip -4 addr show ens33 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')
export TOKEN=$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo)

# turn on etcdctl v3 api support, why is this not default?!
export ETCDCTL_API=3

sudo etcd --name $CL_NAME --data-dir ~/data --advertise-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2379,https://$IP_ADDR:2379 --listen-client-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2379 --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://$IP_ADDR:2380 --listen-peer-urls https://$IP_ADDR:2380 --initial-cluster-state new --initial-cluster-token $TOKEN

# Next come up with a name for the next node, etcd2 then etcd3, etc... Get their hostname/IP and add them as a future member

etcdctl --endpoints="https://127.0.0.1:2379" member add etcd2 --peer-urls="http://<next node's IP address>:2380"

# 1st etcd is now running, with peering available and members 
# added for next nodes
# copy "echo $TOKEN" for next steps where its needed



# On the 1st/next node (I used Centos7 minimal, with etcd installed)
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2379/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2380/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

export CL_NAME=etcd2
export HOST=$(hostname)
export IP_ADDR=$(ip -4 addr show ens33 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')
export ETCDCTL_API=3

export TOKEN=<TOKEN string from above>

sudo etcd --name $CL_NAME --data-dir ~/data --advertise-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://$IP_ADDR:2379 --listen-client-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2379 --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://$IP_ADDR:2380 --listen-peer-urls https://$IP_ADDR:2380 --initial-cluster-state new --initial-cluster-token $TOKEN --initial-cluster="etcd1=http://<IP of 1st node>:2380,etcd2=http://$IP_ADD:2380"

# NOTE the --initial-cluster ALWAYS MUST have all nodes in the
# cluster, with their names and peer urls, otherwise it won't join

# Here's an example for the 3 node
sudo etcd --name $CL_NAME --data-dir ~/data --advertise-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://$IP_ADDR:2379 --listen-client-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2379 --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://$IP_ADDR:2380 --listen-peer-urls https://$IP_ADDR:2380 --initial-cluster-state new --initial-cluster-token $TOKEN --initial-cluster="etcd1=http://<IP of 1st node>:2380,etcd2=http://<IP of 2nd node>:2380,etcd3=http://<IP of 3rd node>:2830"
```

When you get down to 2 running nodes (kill one of them), a new leader will be elected right away. When you're down to 1, the entire effort it useless. If you bring 1 up again, it'll all work again.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your insightful and well-asked question. I'm currently doing a similar investigation. I'm using etcd 3.4, where the API is v3 (not v3beta etc.). I have some partial answers for you at least (formed in part by my own understanding of distributed systems). I'll answer your questions 1 and 3 first, then 2 at the end.

2-node clusters are particularly troublesome for mutable state is concerned, largely because of the 'split-brain' problem, where there is no quorum and neither side (of a network split) has enough knowledge to know it is still authoritative; neither side can safely write any data because there is no useful (or at least generic) way to update the cluster when quorum returns.

2-node clusters in practice would be more tenable for active/passive deployments, such as hosting a floating IP. You can use the  likes of pacemaker to implement HA solutions to coordinate resources such as a floating IP, DRBD block device, filesystem and MariaDB stack (I've done so)... BUT this still comes with the proviso that a 2-node cluster is theoretically (in the sence of sometimes that the risk of split-brain can be accepted).

To make 2-node 'clusters' more robust (to mitigate the risk of split-brain) something else is needed. Here's a few examples:

- pacemaker recommends the use of STONITH (Shoot The Other Node In The Head), which is an example of a 'fencing' mechanism. So if the network inbetween the two nodes goes away and both nodes now think they are the sole remaining node, then the idea is that each node will try and power-off the other (first one wins). This might be interacting with the a power-controller in a cluster, or with a hypervisor. As you can see, this requires a certain level of priviledge with the supporting infrastructure.
- network appliances do often operate as a 2-node cluster, and generally active/passive (its hard enough at times selling the idea of 2 identical pieces of equipment and only using one at a time). In a physical networking deployment, the HA link may be required to be a point-to-point link such as a single fibre pair over which heartbeats are sent. In routing protocols such as BGP this is even a requirement; the idea being that if the remote side powers off the link is seen to go down... lots of subtleties here, such as what happens if one fibre in a fibre-pair were to be broken/degraded.
- I've also seen HA solutions that use some other data in deciding which side of a two-node cluster gets to be the leader. Things like (and this can be a combination and in a particular order) of:

  - comparison of IP address (which is numerically greater or lesser)
  - uptime (last observed uptime)
  - appliance serial number
  - statically configured weighting

All this concern over quorum and split-brain etc. is related to CAP theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem):

- Consistency: Every read receives the most recent write or an error
- Availability: Every request receives a (non-error) response, without the guarantee that it contains the most recent write
- Partition tolerance: The system continues to operate despite an arbitrary number of messages being dropped (or delayed) by the network between nodes

In the event of a network partition, you have to choose between Consistency and Availability. Etcd has made the choice of Consistency; which is *good*, because etcd is a data-store for critical infrastructure. After an event, you really want things to come back up ASAP and without manual and error-prone recovery (ie. just guessing which side of the cluster we should mark as a the authoritative side).

Now, you might be thinking that etcd could at least revert to being able satisfy a read-attempt in the result of a partition; but then that would violate Consistency by risking the delivery of out-of-date information. Etcd also provides some other cluster fundamental services, such as making it easier to do leader elections and locks for your applications; so if etcd were to offer a potentially stale response, that would likely break promises and off-load a lot of the correctness responsibilities onto the clients (so you can bet that would tend not to be done correctly, particularly on anything that might consume its data via some REST/gRPC interface).

This is no different for systems such as Zookeeper, who make a requirement for a three (or five) node cluster much more overt; along with cautions about performance concerns that might cause heartbeat failures (eg. due to garbage collection pauses).

You mention you're on CoreOS, so your application is presumably running in a container. So in terms of HA strategies, you do have another option that people often haven't really considered.... just restart it automatically. At least in Kubernetes (or Openshift, which embodies Kubernetes --- and CoreOS now), if you have HA built into your cluster, then if a container or node were to fail, it can be rescheduled onto a different node.

So if you don't do a three-node etcd service, do a single-node etcd service that can be restarted on failure. That's a viable HA strategy; its not a load-balancing strategy though.

There is also the concept of mirroring, which is supported by etcd and etcdctl has build-in functionality for this. You could use the mirror-maker functionality to create multiple independent HA clusters (say, for a remote site or availability zone). You should generally never operate a *cluster* over a WAN; instead you should *replicate* a cluster.

You'll find this same sort of pattern for etcd, elasticsearch, kafka, etc.

---

With regard to your second question, etcd3 does have a cluster bootstrap facility (https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4.0/dev-internal/discovery_protocol/). In short, you can point your node at another information store and it will get all the same information you would otherwise have to have specified.

To understand the thinking around why etcd3 doesn't work the same as say kafka or elasticsearch cluster membership, you have to think of etcd as providing an infrastructure service -- the base of the pyrimid. You don't want to many dependencies (or assumptions about what traffic might be able to pass or what discovery features might be available).

Etcd could in theory use tools such as cloud-init to obtain things like AWS inventory, but that flexibility is devolved to the user. You should perhaps expect that to be embodied in a script or deployment playbook; its too entangled to do that within etcd and that's a sign of violating separation of concerns, and the expected deployment mechanism should already have all that inventory knowledge.

Kafka and Elasticsearch is kinda interesting to compare here. Kafka gets its cluster membership information from Zookeeper (which is what etcd was designed to replace, and solves much the same sort of problem).

Elasticsearch is interesting because it makes clustering remarkably easy. But that's because it uses sharding and replication, and ends up being quite different in terms of CAP theorem. That's not to say that it sits in the same space as etcd or zookeeper though. In my experience with Elasticsearch I always manually specify all the nodes in my playbook, but Elasticsearch does have more support for discovering its other nodes in environments such as AWS. (cf. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-hosts-providers.html)

Hope that's useful for you,
Cameron